# Thunderbird and Yahoo login, how to pass Captcha without JavaScript?

Tags: thunderbird, javascript, yahoo-mail

I have updated my Yahoo account password and enabled 2FA using an authenticator app. Following that, Yahoo disconnected me from all devices and apps except the current browser. I'm fine with that.

When composing an email in Thunderbird, and the saving of the said email fails due to the Thunderbird OAuth2 authorization having been revoked. Again, I'm fine with that.

Problems start when Thunderbird opens the Yahoo login page, which requires passing a Captcha. However, JavaScript is not enabled (not available?) in the browser window (at least, it looks like it) that Thunderbird has then opened.

But Captcha tells me it requires JavaScript and I see no way to enable JavaScript in Thunderbird for that login page.

I tried copying the address text and putting it in my browser, which enabled me to complete the authorization process. However, this redirected my browser to an address like `http://localhost/?code=xyz` but this, obviously, failed.

I then tried to copy this back to the Thunderbird address bar, to no avail: the address bar is not editable.

I feel stuck with this and I'm calling out to the community here. Is there any other thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the login issue thanks to yet another web search. I came across this link ( https://support.google.com/mail/thread/97731215?hl=en&msgid=98052568 ) which suggested disabling the extensions among other suggestions.

One I disabled the add-ons in Thunderbird and restarted it, the Yahoo login page was shown again, but this time, *without a Captcha*: I had to enter my password and then TOTP code like on a normal web page.

Therefore, I doubt JavaScript was actually a roadblock.